# How to create a column for every value in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am using pandas dataframe to separate a column labeled genres by each genre name, as you can see below. The code to create a list with all the genre names runs fine, but I am also trying to generate a column for each individual genre and am having trouble getting it to print the way I want. Right now, it's only printing one column called x.

```
 genre_list = []
 for genre in goodreads_cl['genre']:
   if genre not in genre_list:
     genre_list.append(genre.split('|'))

 print(genre_list)

 x = genre
 for x in genre_list:
   goodreads_cl['x'] = ''

 goodreads_cl.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `columns` keyword argument to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

In your example,

```
goodreads_cl = pd.DataFrame(columns=genre_list)
```

[image]

Comment: I would have done this but genre_list includes over 20+ names, is there a more efficient way to do this?